# Swift 4: How to set the full background in UIView including Navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to set my background to cover the whole phone on every device including the navigation bar. How can I do this? This is my code below

```
    transparentBackGroundView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to the window as navigationBar overrides the front for any added subview

```
if let vv = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view {
{
    vv.addSubview(transparentBackGroundView)
    transparentBackGroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    transparentBackGroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vv.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    transparentBackGroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vv.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    transparentBackGroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vv.topAnchor).isActive = true
    transparentBackGroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vv.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: can you post the output ?

Comment: The output was the same I had, but the navigation bar wasn't covered. I am trying to cover the navigation bar as well

Answer (score 0):

With Navigation bar on ViewController's view it self does not cover whole phone screen.So you have to do add custom view as navigation bar.

First navigation Controller Screen and In Attributes Inspector uncheck Shows Navigation Bar option.

```
[uncheck Show navigation bar][1]
```

Add a Subview in ViewController's view and give it top leading and trailing of 0 with respect to ViewController's view and give height of 64.This view will work as header or Navigation bar.

add a image view as subview in ViewController's view and I've top bottom leading and trailing 0 with respect to superview.
now giving color or image to image view will cover whole phone screen.